# there exists a nonzero matrices in $M_{2}(\mathbf{C})$ such that $A^{*}_{i}A_{j}$ has trace zero for all $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the largest value of $n$ for which there exists a set $\{A_{1},A_{2},\cdots,A_{n}\}$ of (distinct) nonzero matrices in $M_{2}(\mathbf{C})$ such that $A^{*}_{i}A_{j}$ has trace zero for all $1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n$?

How approach this type question, please give some hints.

Comment: Such a trace represents a positive definite hermitian form on the space of matrices.